# Google App Engine API - Failed to Load Databases - Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google App Engine PHP website with MySQL database.

The website works and the database works correctly. I have connected the database instance to the application and I can access MySQL Client (and can perform queries).

But when I access the Google Cloud SQL API via the Google App Engine Developers Console (on the google developer console website) the database fails to load.

For example:

I select the correct application/database instance. I go on 'Google Cloud SQL' API and then 'SQL Prompts' but get:

```
 Failed to load databases.
```

Any reasons as to why this is happening? and how to load the database? or why  won't the database load in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the link [1] to load your database in your browser.If yes then might be its a browser issue or multiple login problem.

[1] https://console.developers.google.com/project/app-id/sql/instances

Comment: I have my instance there yes. But I am using: https://code.google.com/apis/console the API for Cloud SQL. I already have the database running. But the API allows you to run queries on the browser

Comment: It seems to be a browser issue, just give it a try on different browser.

Comment: No it's not. I have tried on different browsers but that wouldn't make a difference. I have done it on my current browser and it has worked. It's just now it wont